# Execute file on windows host with spaces in path

Tags: windows, ansible

I have a playbook to upload file on remote windows host and then execute it. Problem is that I have a spaces in path and playbook is failing on "Execute file". Here is playbook:

```
- name: Copy file and run
  hosts: terminals
  tasks:
    - name: Copy a single file
      win_copy:
        src: '/tmp/ASDTech Shell Terminal Setup 4.0.0.exe'
        dest: 'C:\Temp\ASDTech Shell Terminal Setup 4.0.0.exe'
    - name: Check if file exist
      win_stat:
        path: 'C:\Temp\ASDTech Shell Terminal Setup 4.0.0.exe'
      register: file_info
    - name: Execute file
      raw: 'C:\Temp\ASDTech Shell Terminal Setup 4.0.0.exe'
      when: file_info.stat.exists == True
```

Error is:

```
TASK [Execute file] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [50.18.46.45]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "stderr": "C:\\\\Temp\\\\ASDTech : The term 'C:\\\\Temp\\\\ASDTech' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or \r\noperable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try \r\nagain.\r\nAt line:1 char:1\r\n+ C:\\\\Temp\\\\ASDTech Shell Terminal Setup 4.0.0.exe\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\\\\Temp\\\\ASDTech:String) [], CommandNotFoundException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException\r\n ", "stderr_lines": ["C:\\\\Temp\\\\ASDTech : The term 'C:\\\\Temp\\\\ASDTech' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or ", "operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try ", "again.", "At line:1 char:1", "+ C:\\\\Temp\\\\ASDTech Shell Terminal Setup 4.0.0.exe", "+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", "    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\\\\Temp\\\\ASDTech:String) [], CommandNotFoundException", "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException", " "], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Can anyone hint me, which module to use, or how to rewrite "Execute file" task, to correctly handle path with spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a bunch of modules to work with on windows,
to execute something, you have `win_shell` (dangerous because of ENVIRONMENT issues) an `win_command` wich you may use.
examples can be found runnin `ansible-doc win_command`

also look at this guide:
[Using Ansible and Windows](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_usage.html)
there are examples of use of `win_command` module, you'll see joyfully you don't have to bother with spaces.